# PHP | Сортировка массив по убыванию по значению

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет. Буду кратен.

Метод вывода массива на экран:

```
function ShowArray($array, $message) {
    printf($message);
    foreach($array as &$value) {
        if(isset($value))
            printf("%d\t", $value);
    }
    unset($value); // разорвать ссылку на последний элемент
    printf("<br/>");
}
```

Дальше я существующий массив $array(1,2,3,4,5) пытаюсь вывести уже отсортированным, но получаю исключение:

```
ShowArray(arsort($array), "ARsort Array: "); // параметры: 1. массив, 2. заголовок
```

***Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\KRYSHTOP-PC\PhpstormProjects\ArraysKryshtopenko\index.php on line 76***

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, и если знаете более лучший способ вывести массив на экран - поделитесь)

Answer (score 1):

Функция [arsort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.arsort.php) возвращает не новый массив, а результат сортировки `true` или `false`. Всё у Вас работает, просто сделайте так:

```
arsort($array);
ShowArray($array, "ARsort Array: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

`arsort` выглядит так:

```
bool arsort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

Работает с массивом по ссылке и:

> Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки

То есть тут:

```
arsort($array)
```

у вас `true` или `false`.

Поэтому в функцию передается не массив, а число (true - 1 или false - 0).

Чтоб отсортировать надо написать сортировку до передачи в функцию

```
arsort($array);    
ShowArray($array, "ARsort Array: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что Вы взяли пример такого кода [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php). 
1) Зачем Вам там ссылка на *$value*, если Вы просто выводите массив на экран? В примере ссылки используют для изменения элементов в массиве, а потом, чтобы в последующем вызове *foreach* **$value** не ссылался на последний элемент в новом цикле. 
2) **arsort** возвращает булевское значение, по этому, массив нужно сортировать перед вызовом метода. 
Перед вызовом метода сортируйте:

```
arsort($array);
```

После уже вызывайте метод:

```
ShowArray($array, "ARsort Array: "); // параметры: 1. массив, 2. заголовок
```

Попробуйте сделать метод таким, на мой взгляд, это подойдет больше:

```
function ShowArray($array, $message) {
printf($message);
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(isset($value)) //спорный момент, т.к. цикл бегает по существующим элементам.
        printf("%d\t", $value);
}
printf("<br/>");
}
```